# How to get refrence of Firebase Realtime databe in Firestore and vice versa in security rules?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I found similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58043947/referencing-firebase-realtime-database-data-through-firestore-security-rules) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62630592/accessing-firestore-from-firebase-realtime-database-security-rules) but there's no solution. I am asking them again expecting any solution.

Is there any possibility to access the Firebase Realtime Database in Firestore security rules?
Actually I want to check if a value exists in Realtime Database from Firestore security rules?

I have a node `admins` in Realtime Database and in Firestore I want to write a security rule if the user exists in `admins` then allows writing. But I couldn't find how to accomplish this?

If I move `admins` node to Firestore then I need to validate admin in Realtime Database. How do I handle this? Please do suggest any best practice to use Firestore and Realtime Database simultaneously.

Comment: The SO answers you refer to are still valid. "It is currently not possible to cross between database products (or Firebase products) in security rules."

Comment: It's not likely to ever be possible.  You should look into alternative solutions, such as mirroring database between the databases, or auth custom claims.

Comment: @DougStevenson Mirroring database means, same data in both places, right? Would you like to explain `auth custom claims`?